# Is it possible that a broadcast receiver continue capturing screen_off and screen_on after closing the application on android?

Tags: android-intent, broadcastreceiver

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF");
filter.addAction("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON");
filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
filter.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
mReceiver = new controlCalls();
registerReceiver(mReceiver,filter);
```

I want to register a BroadcastReceiver that captures these four events and keep it running even if the application is closed, but I have to use unregisterReceiver (mReceiver) and do not know how to fix it.